# redshift: update a Null string into NULL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

There is a redshift table with a "column_a"

```
  column_a                       varchar(1000) null,
```

the following query will return a lot of results in 'Null' strings

```
select column_a from table where lower(column_a)='Null' limit 100;
```

but if i do

```
update table set column_a = NULL where lower(column_a)='';
```

i got an error message

```
Cannot insert a NULL value into column binhash
```

is there anyway i can replace the 'Null' string into NULL? Thanks

Comment: typo. just corrected the description. they are the same column. thanks!

Comment: . . Presumably the column is declared `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me If I haven't understood your question.

AS PER MY UNDERSTANDING

You have a table like this -

```
create table dev.gp_test_20200731
(
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
rolnum int ,
subject varchar(100) null
);
```

Data Like this -

[image]

i.e inserted this way -

```
('abc',01),
('cde',02,'chemistry'),
('def',03,'')
```

So , `rolnum = 1`, has `subject` column as NULL -

```
select * from dev.gp_test_20200731 where subject is null
```

[image]

&
`rolnum = 3`, has `subject` column as `Empty String` or `''`-

```
select * from dev.gp_test_20200731 where subject = ''
```

[image]

Now I am running the update query on `rolnum=3` which is having `subject` column as `empty string`.or in your case it will be a string 'NULL' -

```
update dev.gp_test_20200731 set subject = null  where lower(subject) = ''
```

Result -

```
select * from dev.gp_test_20200731 where subject is null
```

[image]

I am unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: sorry for the late vote! I was out for a vacation! thank you for answering @Golokesh